# Testing against a Docker image server on CircleCI?

Tags: node.js, docker, networking, integration-testing, circleci

I'm trying to write a test suite for my application.  My application is a downloader; it takes arbitrary web request information (URLs, headers, cookies, etc) and sends a request and returns the response.

In order to test the downloading functionality of this application, I'm trying to stand up an instance of [HttpBin](http://httpbin.org/) inside my test environment using their provided Docker image, run queries against it, and then spin it down once the test is done.  Clearly I can't run this except through Docker, as it is a Docker image that is provided.

This all works fine on my local machine; I can spin up the image, set up port-forwarding, and send my queries and receive responses.  The problem is, I can't seem to make this work when I run m test in my CI/CD pipeline (powered by CircleCI).  For some reason, I can't get my test server to talk to my HttpBin instance no matter what I try.  I've tried checking the locations of the 2 images and I got something that looks like this when I run `docker container list` on CircleCI:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                            COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                  PORTS                               NAMES
74b99c53fd97   kennethreitz/httpbin                             "gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0…"   1 second ago     Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp   httpbin
5d27d41efd94   cimg/node:lts-browsers                           "/docker-entrypoint.…"   30 seconds ago   Up 27 seconds                                               jolly_golick
```

So it appears that the HttpBin instance and my test instance (running inside an `lts-browsers` instance) are both child VMs running inside an integration server, and it looks like port-forwarding is set up from the integration server to HttpBin, meaning I should be able to make `host.docker.internal` calls, but those don't work (`ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this work?  It seems like a common enough use case for E2E/Integration testing that it really should work and it's odd that it doesn't.

Also, here's my test config from `package.json`:

```
{
    "pretest": "docker stop httpbin || true && docker container rm httpbin || true && docker run -d -p 80:80 --name=httpbin kennethreitz/httpbin",
    "test": "jest",
    "posttest": "docker stop httpbin && docker container rm httpbin"
}
```